# VueJS - Import a global scss in all .vue components

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, sass, vuejs2

I'm using Vue JS with ASP .NET Core, I started the project from [this template](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-Vue-starter) on GitHub (not from Vue CLI). The project loads fine, but I'm willing to use SCSS so that I can include a global file containing variables and mixins across all the vue components.

The '*stone age*' solution would be to include the file in every component template but this repeats the same contents across all components.

I then found that I can preload a global scss file using webpack, so I followed multiple documentations ([here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/guide/css.md#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders), [here](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/) and [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html) to name a few) but nothing seems to work. I still get 'undefined variable' once I try to use a variable inside a component like so:

```
<style lang="scss">
h1 {
    color: $danger;
}
</style>
```

Where `$danger` is defined in `_variables.scss` found at `./ClientApp/styles`.

I tried to configure SASS loader as follows (`~styles` is an alias defined in the config):

```
      use: [
        'vue-style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            data: `
              @import "~styles/_variables.scss";
            `
          }
        }
      ]
```

Even installing `vue add style-resources-loader` and configuring it in in `vue.config.js` like so:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      // pass options to sass-loader
      sass: {
        data: `@import "~styles/global.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm starting to think that this have to do with how ASP.NET Core handles SPA applications or some misconfiguration of Webpack but I have no clue what to try next.

Answer (score 2):

Given you tried to set it up with your first bit of code, I assume you are using vue-cli 2 and not 3.

If that is the case, then you need to modify the configuration for the vue-loader and not the sass loader.

In `./build/utils.js`, you should add options to the `generateLoaders()` function as such:

```
return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less', {
      enableJavascript: true
    }),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', {
      indentedSyntax: true
    }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass', {
      data: `@import "${path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/your_file.scss")}";` // THIS LINE
    }),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
}
```

You will be able to use your SASS variables in any component without having to import it.

Comment: you can also use 
scss: generateLoaders('sass', {
      data: `@import "@/scss/your_file.scss")}";`
    }),